# How to change inline css using jquery in joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla

I tried to change inline css using jquery. but it not change.

This is my html code

```
<div class="page1" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/1.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div class="page2" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/2.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div class="page3" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/3.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
<div class="page4" style="background: url(modules/mod_test/tmpl/img/4.jpg); width:100%;"></div>
```

this is the code i wrote

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.test-img').click(function() {
            $('.page1').css("background", "images/1.jpg","width", "100%");
$('.page2').css("background", "images/2.jpg","width", "100%");
$('.page3').css("background", "images/3.jpg","width", "100%");
$('.page4').css("background", "images/4.jpg","width", "100%");
        });   
    });
```

But it not change the image. can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: try this.
$('.page1').css({"width":"100%","background": "url(images/1.jpg)"});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general use [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function like this:

```
$('your_element').css({'prop_one': 'prop_one_value', 'prop_two': 'prop_two_value', ... });
```

So, in your case you forgot `{}` and you did not assign the css rules correctly `'prop':'value'` :

```
$('.page1').css({"background": "url('images/1.jpg')","width": "100%"});
```

Comment: Supply a description and this answer would be perfect

Comment: @kapantzak it's working. but it not display the path correctly. so image not display.do u know how to get the correct path here?

Comment: You need to find the relative or absolute path of your image. Check here for more details (http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

Comment: thanks @kapantzak. it's working. but there is a another problem. when i go back it change to earlier one. do u have any idea about it how to fix?

Comment: What do you mean 'when I go back'? Can you provide a live link?

Comment: this is a look book. it include pages.when come back to first page it display earlier one.

Comment: @kapantzak i edited the question. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I found some syntax errors inside CSS declaration in your script. You should refer [jQuery API doc for CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/) first. And need to debug using browser's inspector/debugger tool.

Here you missed **curly braces {}** and **colon :** inside syntax. I have changed to correct one in below snippet.

Further you should go through doc in Joomla for [Adding JavaScript and CSS](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page).

**Improved Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.test-img').click(function() {
            $('.page1').css({"background": "images/1.jpg","width": "100%"});
        });   
    });
});
```

In case if you are using other JavaScript libraries like MooTools or YUI, you can change it to specific:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.test-img').click(function() {
            $('.page1').css({"background": "images/1.jpg","width": "100%"});
        });   
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

For defining **multiple** css properties with jQuery, you need seperate each property value with `:` and seperate each css property with a `,` and

Try like this:

```
$('.page1').css({"background":"url('images/1.jpg')","width":"100%"});
```

---

Also **single** css property typing example this:

```
$('.page1').css("background","images/1.jpg");
```

[**Here is jQuery api css referance.**](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: this won't work, css background property is invalid enclose with `url(..)`.